# EF 4.1 Codefirst: Instantiate complex navigation properties

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

imagine having a simple POCO for EF 4.1 Codefirst:

```
public class Product
{
    // Native properties 
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    public Product()
    {
        this.ID = Guid.NewGuid();

        // Do I have to instantiate navigation properties in the constructor or not???
        this.Category = new Category();
        this.Customers = new List<Customer>();
    }
}
```

What I couldn't figure out so far is if I should instantiate complex navigation properties in the POCO's constructor or not?

Seems like all my current code is working if I don't instantiate, but I'm concerned that my code might cause problems in the future.

Are there any rules, best practices or any side effects?

Thanks for your ideas and tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to instantiate `Category`. Category is single entity which either exists or not - Product is not responsible for its creation. You can need to instantiate `Customers` to empty list.

The reason why it works now is because your context will wrap entities with dynamic proxy which will handle instantiation of you `Customers` collection. Because of that other code can access the collection without receiving `NullReferenceException`. This can change if you create instance of `Product` in your code without using EF. In such case there will be no dynamic proxy and your collection will be null = you will have to instantiate it yourselves.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations, Ladislav.

Comment: If I interpret your answer correctly, EF wraps all dependent entities with proxies automatically? No matter if they are single or lists?

Comment: EF wraps entities with dynamic proxies. There are some basic rules which must be followed for this to happen: it must be allowed on the context (default), lazy loading must be allowed (default), all navigation properties must be virtual.

Comment: Alright. But where is the difference between my Category and my Customers? In case of the Category you wrote I don't have to instantiate it. And in case of the Customers you wrote that I might need to create them. I still don't get the general idea here...

Comment: Because `Category` is an entity reference. If you assign it you are creating database relation = you don't want to create database relation each time you work with `Product`. `Customers` is a collection - it alone is not related to EF until you start filling it with `Customer` entities and to fill it it must be initialized.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks again for your nice and detailed information, Ladislav. Helped me a lot!